# Which UI Prototype tool should I use?

Tags: user-interface, web, drop-down-menu, dropdownbox

I have been searching for UI prototype tools which requires little/no coding, along with decent UI features. In one project, I would like to be able to implement a drop down list which the user picks a choice, which can affect the list of choices shown by another drop down list. Mind me, I am fairly new to UI/UX design and web design. And no, I would not like to use HTML due to its inflexibility and it being difficult to modify/extend. Any suggestion of good UI tools, whether be it free or paid?

Answer (score 1):

Probably should try using Microsoft Visual Studio Community or Enterprise. Community is the minimum but Enterprise has much greater number of benefits. Then, get the web development workload in order to use ASP.NET to develop the type of form you intend to get.